# How do you properly escape a sed command in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I can run this command from the command line to get the value for the latest release in a GitHub repo:

curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrg/MyRepo/releases/latest"|grep "tag_name"|sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'

I'd like to use this in a Jenkinsfile, but I can't seem to properly escape the special characters.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
            sh """
            latest=`curl --silent \\\"https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrg/MyRepo/releases/latest\\\"|
            grep \\\"tag_name\\\"|
            sed -E \\\'s/.*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\".*/\1/\\\'`
            """.stripIndent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run in a pipeline, I get the following error:

[Pipeline] sh

- curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrg/MyRepo/releases/latest"
- grep "tag_name"
- sed -E 's/.*"
  sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Answer (score 0):

instead of wrapping the large expression in backticks, try instead wrapping it in

```
$(command_1 | command_2 | command_3)
```

Also add, at the start of the shell command:

```
set -x;
```

and you'll get debug output in the console output (possibly). You should then see how your script is being evaluated.